Microsoft Edge forcing extension side bar into dark mode
We have a browser extension that uses the side_panel feature in manifest v3. This side panel renders an iframe that points to a live sit.
The colors in the site are in "light mode". It has dark text on a light background.
However, I have Microsoft Edge in dark mode and it seems intent on overriding the colors in the iframe to be dark.
For example, this snippet:
<div style="color: black; background-color: white;">Here is some text</div>

Renders as white text on a black backrgound:

Changing the colors with the color picker, you can see that Edge basically flips the color when its saturation reaches 50%.
If I turn off dark mode in Edge, then the side panel renders as expected.
Is there a way to turn this off? We really want the side bar to always be rendered in light mode, regardless of the browser's settings.
I tried applying this CSS rule to both the sidebar's HTML and the iframe:
html {
    color-scheme: light;
}

...but it has no effect.
I also tried turning off edge://flags/#enable-force-dark and restarting the browser, but the forced dark mode persists.
Any clues as to how to disable this for our extension?

Finally figured it out; we had to add this to the iframe:
html {
   color-scheme: only light;
}

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color-scheme

only: Forbids the user agent from overriding the color scheme for the element.

Google also details other opt-out methods, such as a meta tag, here: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/auto-dark-theme/#how_to_opt-out_of_auto_dark_theme
